# How reload view controller like first time in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit

How reload viewcontraller like first time in Swift 4? 
Details: when run app then enter viewcontraller then exit from it and I want back to same viewcontraller I want download viewcontraller from new same first time.

```
//code close viewcontraller :
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})

//code on enter or back to viewcontraller :
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sbmpo2", sender: nil)    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign data to the ViewController or making API calls inside `viewWillAppear` that will call everytime when you came to that viewcontroller. Only you have to do to call data population functions/API call inside viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        //call your data populating/API calls from here

}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I did that but same problem

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following methods of `UIViewController`:

- [viewWillAppear(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear)
- [viewDidAppear(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear)
- [viewWillDisappear(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear)
- [viewDidDisappear(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621477-viewdiddisappear)

The first two are called each time the view is shown. The last two are called each time the view goes away.

You can override these methods in your `ViewController` to setup your view as you wish.

Comment: I did that but same promblem

Answer (score 0):

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {

    //UIViewController is dismissed

    DispatchQueue.main.async 
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sbmpo2", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you